# Jquery mask is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I am using the mask plugin into my project. I have included it like this;

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Even though I am able to use the mask method like this and it works without a problem;

```
$("#txtTel").mask("+380 999 999 999")
```

I am not able to use it to change its definitios like this;

```
 $.mask.definitions['9'] = '';
 $.mask.definitions['#'] = '[0-9]';
```

It gives me this error;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'definitions' of undefined
```

What can be causing this problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: when do you call the .mask method ? it will not work because it probably runs before the rest of the page is parsed.

wrap the call within document.ready:

$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#txtTel").mask("+380 999 999 999");
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using one plugin with the documentation from another.

The syntax you're using applies to this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.maskedinput

... not to the one you're using.